# Angular 2 route resolver not working, browser blank and no errors in console

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-resolver

I implemented a route resolver but the entire target component (events-list.component.ts) is not shown in the browser. I only see the navbar. As shown below, the resolver gets the list of events from the events service. And no errors are shown in the Chrome developer tools console. I also tried loading the app in the Firefox browser, but the problem still persists. What could be wrong with my code? Thanks.

**routes.ts file**

The 'events' route is the default route which I am having the problem with.

```
import {Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { EventDetailsComponent } from './events/event-details/event-details.component';
import { EventsListComponent } from './events/events-list.component';
import { CreateEventComponent } from './events/create-event.component';
import { Error404Component } from './errors/404.guard';
import { EventRouteActivator } from './events/event-details/event-route-activator.service';
import { EventListResolver } from './events/event-list-resolver.service';

export const appRoutes: Routes = [

    {path: 'events/new', component: CreateEventComponent, canDeactivate: ['canDeactivateCreateEvent']},
    {path: 'events', component: EventsListComponent, resolve: {events: EventListResolver}},
    {path: 'events/:id', component: EventDetailsComponent, canActivate: [EventRouteActivator]},
    {path: '404', component: Error404Component},
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'events', pathMatch: 'full'}
]
```

**event.service.ts file**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EventService {

  constructor() { }

  events = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Angular Connect',
      date: '9/26/2036',
      time: '10:00 am',
      price: 599.99,
      imageUrl: '/assets/images/angularconnect-shield.png',
      onlineUrl: 'http://ng-nl.org/'
     },

    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'ng-nl',
      date: '4/15/2037',
      time: '9:00 am',
      price: 950.00,
      imageUrl: '/assets/images/ng-nl.png',
      location: {
        address: 'The NG-NL Convention Center & Scuba Shop',
        city: 'Amsterdam',
        country: 'Netherlands'
      }
}
  ];

  getEvents(){
    let subject = new Subject();
    setTimeout(() => {subject.next(this.events); subject.complete;}, 2000)
    return subject;
  }

  getEvent(id: number){
  return this.events.find(event => event.id === id);
  }
}
```

**resolver.service.ts file**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { EventService } from '../shared/event.service';
import { Resolve } from '@angular/router';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class EventListResolver implements Resolve<any>{

    constructor(private eventService: EventService){

    }

    resolve() { 
        return this.eventService.getEvents().pipe(map(events => events));
    }

}
```

**event-list.component.ts file**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EventService } from '../shared/event.service';
import { ToastrService } from '../shared/toastr.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './events-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./events-list.component.css']
})
export class EventsListComponent implements OnInit {

  events: any[];

  constructor(private eventService: EventService, private toastrService: ToastrService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.events = this.route.snapshot.data['events'];
  }

  handleThumbnailClick(eventName){
  this.toastrService.success(eventName)
  }
}
```

**events-list.component.html**

```
<div>
    <h1>Upcoming angular events</h1>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5" *ngFor="let event of events" >
        <event-thumbnail [event]="event" (click)="handleThumbnailClick(event.name)"></event-thumbnail>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I don't even see the h1 tag's text "Upcoming angular events". I only see the navbar and then the rest of the page is blank.

**events-app.component.ts file (main bootstrapped component)**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'events-app',
  template: `<nav-bar></nav-bar>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
  //styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class EventsAppComponent {
  title = 'ng-fundamentals';
}
```

Comment: since you dont see the <h1> tag, **event-list.component** itself is not instantiated(since not routed to that component). The route resolver probably is not returning proper observable/promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you dont even see the static `<h1>` tag, `event-list.component` itself is not instantiated(since not routed to that component). The route resolver probably is not returning proper observable/promise

can you try with below code -

**event.service.ts**

```
getEvents(){
  return of(this.events).pipe(delay(2000)); //if you need delay
}
```

**resolver.service.ts**

```
resolve(){
  return this.eventService.getEvents();
}
```

and debug in **event-list.component.ts** `ngOnInit`, whether the `events` data is resolved

Comment: You have to import those methods from rxjs - 

`import { of } from 'rxjs';`
`import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Comment: I tried adding the imports but for some reason it was saying it couldn't find the operators, but I just let vs code auto import it and the resolver is working now. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Although you have not shared your template but I am assuming that you are trying to render the `events` of your component. If my understanding is correct then you are not assigning `events` from the route data. You should do the following -

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.events = this.route.snapshot.data['events'];
 }
```

The problem is in `getEvents()` method. You are returning subject even before the `subject.next()` emits the value and meantime your resolver will resolve before 2 seconds and resolver will return empty events.

Let's change the `getEvents()` method like this -

```
getEvents() {
  return of(this.events).pipe(delay(2000))
}
```

Comment: I added your code, but the problem is still there. I have added the html template to my original post above. thanks.